Understanding expansion of the Universe as things flying apart
Say that we have a Universe uniformly filled just with matter (let's not bring dark energy into this). And say that we fill it with very light particles (so that the gravitational interaction between individual particles can be neglected) that follow the expansion of the Universe, so their proper distance is increasing following Hubble's law. Now we grab two of those particles and change their relative velocity so that they are stationary with respect to each other. Will they keep a constant proper distance, considering we can neglect their mutual gravitational attraction?
I guess my question is really about what is expanding in the Universe. Can the Universe be pretty much seen just as things flying away from each other with this "momentum" being created at the Big Bang? Or is the space actually something that wants to expand everywhere and unless the two particles are bound by some force, the expansion will kick in and they will slowly start separating again?

I think this is a repeat question. Anyway you might find answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422892/is-space-expansion-causing-increasing-distances-between-galaxies/674077#674077

... or here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter/441211#441211

The scenario: within a matter-dominated universe, you have prepared two particles with initially constant separation.
In this scenario, those two particles will begin to fall toward each other. This is not due to their mutual attraction and not a consequence of any kind of "expansion of space". Rather, it is due to the collective gravity of the whole matter distribution -- especially the gravitational attraction of the matter that lies between the two particles.
It is correct to say that, in the absence of dark energy, you can understand cosmic expansion simply as particles flying apart with momentum left over from the Big Bang. "Expansion of space" is not really a physical phenomenon; as discussed in other answers:

Space expansion is a description of the coordinates and not the physics.
There is no concept of "expanding space" in general relativity.
Expansion of space is not distinguishable from objects moving away.


“you can understand cosmic expansion simply as particles flying apart with momentum” - In this interpretation the cosmological horizon does not exist. Does it exist in FLRW without dark energy?

@safesphere It is correct that a matter/radiation universe has no event horizon. (It still has a particle horizon of course, due to it's finite age.)

But there is no particle horizon in the universe with “cosmic expansion simply as particles flying apart with momentum”  (the Milne model) is there?

@safesphere I am not, nor is the question, referring to a universe without gravity.

The question does mention neglecting gravity, but either way gravity is not the point. The point is that there is no particle horizon in the universe expanding as an explosion in a flat space. How does this work with your statement that this scenario is physically equivalent to the expanding space?

@safesphere The question mentions neglecting gravity between individual particles, not gravity of the collective distribution. And where did I say flat space or flat spacetime? Of course the spacetime of the universe is not flat.

Once again, gravity is not the point. You said: “you can understand cosmic expansion simply as particles flying apart with momentum left over from the Big Bang” - Here “flying apart with momentum” is contrasted to the expanding space and usually assumes a flat Minkowski spacetime. If you meant some other non-expanding spacetime, then you did not clarify its type. Although it doesn’t matter either, because the absence of the particle horizon relates to the absence of expansion, not to flatness. Will you revise your answer or insist that the space expansion is equivalent to momentum?

@safesphere The spacetime is FLRW (or more specifically Einstein-de Sitter). Cosmic expansion within the context of FLRW is most naturally understood as objects flying apart, as detailed in the linked answers and the articles linked therein.


Can the Universe be pretty much seen just as things flying away from each other [...] ?

Absolutely! This is precisely what expansion means. That nearby particles are moving apart. (Technically, the expansion tensor for their trajectories is nonzero). Concepts like "stretching of space" are not fundamental physical principles, nor new forces. Rather they are, in part, just language and interpretation. In contrast, relative motion (for nearby particles) is a physically measurable quantity.
As for the Hubble flow, I'll tweak your question to remove the assumption of "very light" matter. I'll just take the two test particles themselves to be small and light, so their mutual gravity may be ignored. Consider firstly a single test particle. If it moves relative to the Hubble flow, this is called a peculiar velocity. In an expanding universe, this velocity decreases over time, whereas in a shrinking universe it would increase. (See e.g. Carroll 2004 §8.5 for the technical details.) Intuitively, this is simply because it catches up with the other matter, in an expanding universe. As it turns out, the distance between your two test particles will not remain constant, in general. Also, while a test particle will gradually rejoin the Hubble flow, in the sense of decreasing peculiar velocity; this will not generally be in its original "location", by which I mean not next to its original neighbours. We need to be careful with terminology here, in fact Barnes et al (2006) analyse 7 different definitions!
We could generalise this discussion beyond homogeneous and isotropic universes. Consider a small cloud of test particles in an arbitrary spacetime. The change in its volume over time is given by both its initial internal motion, such as any rotation, as well as the spacetime curvature. Those wanting further details should look up the Raychaudhuri equation. Similarly the cloud may elongate into an egg/football/ellipsoid; there is an analogous equation for this shear (e.g. Ellis+ 2012 §6.4).

Interesting question. If such a hypothetical universe existed without gravitational attraction all objects in motion or at rest would tend to stay that way and most of the particles that exist in our universe today would not exist in this experimental universe.  We might not be able to build a device to 'grab' those particles and change their position. Regarding the expansion of the universe; everything is flying apart in every direction.  One difference between the big bang and other explosions is for others we can reverse calculate 'where' in space the explosion took place. When we try to do this for the big bang the 'explosion' happened everywhere. And yes galaxies are flying apart. In addition to the matter flying apart the fabric of space time is actually stretching/expanding as time moves forward. The 'graph paper' we are stretching on is at the planck scale.

NOTE: I have made a significant revision to this answer and the conclusions are different to the previous version.

Or is the space actually something that wants to expand everywhere and
unless the two particles are bound by some force, the expansion will
kick in and they will slowly start separating again?

As explained below, even in the expanding spacetime model, there is no drag on objects due to the Hubble flow. The two objects will not start separating again. As Sten pointed out in his answer they will tend to drift together again due to the gravity of matter between them in a non empty universe. The expanding spacetime concept does mean that massive objects at rest with bulk flow will experience no time dilation and that the worldlines of photons are different in the two models. In the expanding spacetime time model the redshift is attributed to the 'stretching' of photons as they travel through the expanding space. In the kinematic model the redshift is due to relativistic Doppler shift and to a certain extent there is an opposing blue shift due to gravitational potential in a non empty universe. Common analogies such as transparent disks stuck on the surface of an inflating rubber balloon, are misleading. A common misconception is that objects have to be 'locally bound' to resist the expansion. Consider an exaggerated scenario for visual effect. imagine we tether a large object somewhere far outside or galaxy where the recession velocity is 0.5c to something fairly stationary inside our galaxy and cut the tether. What happens if we cut the tether? To first order both models predict nothing! There will however be slight inward drift due to gravitational effects. As Peacock explains in his paper, we can imagine a sphere of low density matter enclosing one object and the other object is on the surface of that enclosing sphere. There is a gravitational potential due to that enclosed matter. We can consider the gravitational attraction of the total mass in the enclosed  sphere to be equivalent to the same mass concentrated as a point at the centre of the sphere as per Newton's shell theorem.
Wikipedia states "In reality, the expansion of the universe can alternatively be thought of as corresponding only to the inertial motion of objects away from one another."
The same Wikipedia article also states "Contrary to common misconception, it is equally valid to adopt a description in which space does not expand and objects simply move apart while under the influence of their mutual gravity.{2}{3}{4}"
{2} Peacock (2008), arXiv:0809.4573
{3} Bunn & Hogg, American Journal of Physics 77, pp. 688–694 (2009), arXiv:0808.1081
{4} Lewis, Australian Physics 53(3), pp. 95–100 (2016), arXiv:1605.08634 n
Let's compare two basic models, the SR ballistic model in flat spacetime (essentially the flying apart model) and a Hubble flow model based on the FLWR metric which assumes space is expanding. While in a matter dominated universe, there is an effect on observed redshift due to gravitational potential, I have deliberately ignored the effects of gravitation in order to isolate and focus on the effects on observed red shift due to kinematic effects.
Let's say we observe a very distant, high z, supernova event that appears to be 42 billion light years away from calculations based of its luminosity. The SR model always predicts a recession velocity of less than the speed of light so it has difficulty explaining how an object can be 42 billion billion light years away when the universe is thought to be only about 14 billion years old. This does not mean the ballistic SR model is fatally flawed, because what everyone forgets to take into account is relativistic beaming, which reduces the observed brightness of the object making it appear further away than it really is. Relativistic beaming explains why the object appears to be 42 billion light years away and appears to have a velocity of about 3c. The SR model also agrees with the HF model on observed Doppler time dilation, without any modification. This does not make the two models agree in every detail. There are subtle differences, as detailed below and the predicted distance vs redshift are slightly different as illustrated in the graph right at the end of this answer. This has consequences for whether the apparent acceleration of the expansion is just an artifact of using the expansion model. Of course we can also explain the observed distances, by giving the distant galaxy a head start of 28 billion light years during the inflation period just after the big bang, but this is a form of (extreme) space expansion in itself. I explore the differences of the two models in much greater detail below:
Another thing the SR flying apart model has difficulty explaining is the apparent accelerating expansion of the universe. However this recent paper that has been peer reviewed and published in a respectable journal casts serious doubt on the accelerating expansion hypothesis.
As requested by the OP, gravitational attraction between galaxies is treated as being negligible and accelerating expansion due to dark energy is ignored.
Basic definitions of the two models:



Quantity
SR Ballistic Model
Hubble Flow Model




Time dilation
A distant galaxy is subject to time dilation as a function of its velocity relative to us as per SR. Even objects conforming to the Hubble velocity distance relationship  are subject to time dilation.
A distant galaxy is only subject to time dilation if it has velocity relative to the bulk flow (local or peculiar velocity)


Bulk flow Recession Velocity
$v_r = \frac{z(z+2)}{z(z+2)+2}$
$ v_r = Log(1+z)$


Maximum velocity
Speed of light (c)
< Infinite


Distance when emitted
$D_e = \frac{T_{Now} \ z(z+2)}{2z(z+2)+2}$
$D_e = \frac{T_{now} \ Log(1+z)}{(1+z)}$


Light travel time
$T_{ltt} = D_e/c$
$T_{ltt} = D_e(e^{v_r}-1)/v_r $


Distance (Lum)
$D_{lum} = D_e \frac{(1+v_r)^{(3/2-\alpha/2)}}{(1-v_r^2)^{(3/4-\alpha/4)}}$
$D_{lum} = D_e (1+z)$


Apparent recession velocity
$V_a = D_{lum}/T_{now}$
$V_a = D_{lum}/T_{now}$



An alternative expression for $D_{Lum}$ in the Hubble flow model is $ Log(1+z)T_{now} \quad$.
The SR luminosity equation is complicated because it has to take into account the effect of relativistic beaming on the apparent luminosity of an object. It is something that must be taken into account, because it is an unavoidable prediction of special relativity. In the equation, $\alpha$ is the spectral index of the observed object. This has a value of between zero (for mostly high frequencies) and 2 (observed spectrum concentrated at low frequencies). $V_r$ is the observed recession velocity of a galaxy at rest in the bulk Hubble flow. The relativistic beaming effect that is completely ignored in all cosmology papers is a key factor in allowing the SR flying apart model to match observations.

In the above diagram assume a supernova event occurs at J and the proper time interval of this event is 20 days. (D to S). Doppler time dilation predicts a time dilation factor of (z+1), so a supernova that has z=1 should be seen over a period of 40 days. This has been confirmed by actual observations. For a model to be valid it must be able to reproduce this time dilation factor. In the above diagram the SR model is on the left and the HF model is on the right. Both models reproduce the    (z+1) Doppler time dilation factor. For the SR model, the coordinate time interval of the event is 25 days due to time dilation. It also occurs at a later cosmological coordinate time in the SR model, but due to SR time dilation the proper age works out the same as in the expanding model. There is exact agreement between the two models in this comparison and the signals arrive at the same time. Where they differ slightly is in the predicted distance from the observer of the supernova event.

In the above diagram the dashed line represents a projectile in the SR Ballistic model that is launched at 0.5c. In this model its motion is entirely due to its initial momentum. If there is a galaxy also moving at 0.5c away from us that is at rest with the bulk Hubble flow (blue worldline) and initially at 50 units distance, the projectile will never catch up with distant galaxy and in fact will remain at 50 units distance away from it for all time in the SR model. Previously I incorrectly stated the HF model predicts the projectile will follow the trajectory represented by the solid red curve, but this was based on the assumption that a projectile with mass would comply with the same equation of motion as a photon. The massive projectile would in fact follow the dashed straight path in both models. A consequence of this fact is that in both models any inertially moving massive object will asymptotically come to rest locally in the Hubble flow.
The reason a light particle behave differently to a massive particle is that it has to maintain a local peculiar velocity of c and loses energy by changing to a lower frequency or longer wavelength. The massive particle on the other hand loses energy by slowing down it peculiar velocity. Similar behaviour can be seen in the Schwarzschild metric. A projectile fired upwards slows down locally and eventually comes to a stop. A photon climbing out of the gravitational well always has a local velocity of c but loses energy by changing wavelength instead.
The x coordinate of a photon moving outwards in the same direction as the Hubble flow as a function of time in the expanding universe model is given by:
$x_{out} = \frac{c}{V_h} \ \ln\left(1+\frac{V_h t}{D_e}\right) (D_e+V_h t)$
where $V_h$ is now the local Hubble flow velocity of a target galaxy and $D_e$ represents the distance of the target galaxy at the time the photon left. The photon trajectory would be more like the solid red curve in the above graph.
As mentioned at the start and as discussed above, inertial objects will move in exactly the same way in both models. Two objects that are initially at rest with respect to each other and initially comoving will maintain constant spatial separation as illustrated in the diagram below by the dashed purple trajectories. However it can be noted that over time the separation of the two objects appears to be getting smaller, because while they maintain constant separation relative to each other surrounding galaxies are moving apart relative to them.

In the next chart, I have plotted the luminosity distances against observed redshift for both models. The orange curve is the luminosity distance according to the SR Ballistic model and the blue curve is the distance according to the HF model. I have assumed a value of $\alpha = 1.6$ for the above plot as this value gives distances in the same ball park as each other.  In this answer I have not taken a position on which model is the correct model. However, IFF the SR ballistic model is the correct model, using the Hubble flow model would incorrectly predict that low to medium z objects are too far away and high z objects are too close, creating an illusion of accelerating expansion.

Wolfram equation and plot here.

I don't understand why you deleted your earlier answer and posted this one with only minor changes. The old answer still had those comments underneath it, so you wouldn't have had to copy-paste them into the answer body.

This answer (like the last one) starts with the wrong assumption that the first paper you linked is talking about an SR ballistic model in flat spacetime. It's actually talking about the same standard FLRW cosmology as the second paper. The statement in the abstract that "it is always valid to choose a coordinate system that is locally Minkowskian" is a true statement about GR. It doesn't mean that spacetime is globally flat.

@benrg You probably didn't see the note at the top that I was still carrying out a major re-edit of my answer. I had changed some of my conclusions so most of the previous comments were no longer relevant. I also changed some diagrams and deleted about half the answer as it was (and probably still is) far too long. I wanted to keep some of the formulas that I deleted for my own future reference. The easiest way to keep those formulas was delete the answer as I still have access to the deleted answer.

@benrg Wikipedia states "In reality, the expansion of the universe can alternatively be thought of as corresponding only to the inertial motion of objects away from one another." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe#Conceptual_considerations_and_misconceptions

@benrg "It doesn't mean that spacetime is globally flat." I agree. I have edited my answer yet again to acknowledge that spacetime on cosmological scales is not flat and that gravitational potential does have does have an effect. I have also explained that I chose to ignore the gravitational effect to concentrate on the effects of kinematic motion on redshift and other cosmological observations.

@benrg "It's actually talking about the same standard FLRW cosmology as the second paper. " However that paper makes it clear that it attributes the observed redshift to kinematic (and gravitational) effects and not due to the expansion of space , which is the common interpretation of the FLRW model.  So while both papers are talking about FLWR cosmology, the interpretations of what is observed are very different.
